# where should i store jwt for mobile auth

Tags: react-native, express, passport.js, jwt

**should i store token using cookie or asyncStorage to use it to check if user login by passport-jwt**

```
const cookieExtractor = (req) => {
    let token = null
    if(req && req.cookies){
        token = req.cookies.jwt
    }
    console.log(token)
    return token
}

passport.use(new jwtStrategy({jwtFromRequest:cookieExtractor,secretOrKey:'sphinx'},(payload,done) => {
    user.findById(payload.userId,(err,User) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err,false)
        }
        if(User){
            return done(null,User)
        }else{
            return done(null,false)
        }
    })
}))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `expo-secure-store`.

`expo-secure-store` provides a way to encrypt and securely store key–value pairs locally on the device.

To use it, you first install using `expo install expo-secure-store`

After install, in your code, you will import it using `import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'`

Now, to use `expo-secure-store` you can use:

```
SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value, options) //to set one item
SecureStore.getItemAsync(key, options) //to get one item
SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key, options) //to delete one item
```

I will give one example when I set one key with one function to signin:

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'

const signin = dispatch => async ({ token }) => {
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', token)
};
```

You can learn more about `expo-secure-store` [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)